# Training or flight-training, maintenance-training, and atc-training?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

How should we use tags like training?  It is a general topic, and I suggest using more specific tags since we are targeting more than just pilots so that we can find questions a little easier:  [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training), [maintenance-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-training), and [atc-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atc-training) would be a good start.  If anyone has more appropriate tags I'm more than open to suggestion.

Comment: I'm leaning toward the more specific tags here because [tag:training] will probably devolve into a meta tag - It really can't stand on it's own because there are so many things you could be training for...

Comment: @voretaq7 I agree, put that as an answer so that we can see if others do too.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update:*** [training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) has been renamed to [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training). If you see the training tag, please edit the question to use [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training), [atc-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atc-training), or [maintenance-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-training).

---

I like the idea of separating maintenance/atc/flight training. Clearly all of them are different, and all of them would be on-topic here, so that seems like common sense.

There are two things which I think are less clear.

**First**, is [maintenance-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance-training) the proper name for a tag like that? No one has used it yet, but we'll have to decide when it comes along. In the US at least, we generally refer to them as A&P's, though I don't know if that's a common term around the world. Also, `a&p` can't be used as a tag name, it would have to be [a-and-p](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-and-p), which I don't particularly like. [mechanic-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanic-training) would also be a possibility. Just opening it up for discussion.

**Second**, is "flight-training" specific enough? We often refer to the specific type of training you're doing, such as private/primary training, instrument training, commercial, multi-engine, atp, helicopter, seaplane, [endless list here]. I lean towards saying [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training) (probably a synonym with [pilot-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilot-training)) is enough. It can always be made implicitly more specific by combining it with other relevant tags. Again, I felt like this should be addressed so we're all on the same page first.

Comment: For First, I was using the verb form instead of the noun which is why I used maintenance instead of mechanic.  They maintain/repair airplanes, they don't A&P them.  :)  We could use the noun form though (I'm not against that).  For Second, I think that flight-training is specific enough, and that we should have tags for each license that can go along with it, as well as have questions on their own.

Comment: Also, there is more to maintenance training than just A&P's. There are also IA's, etc. that require training as well.

Comment: @lnafziger I was essentially agreeing with you on everything - just pointing out that there were a few more points worth bringing into the realm of discussion.

Comment: Yup, and I appreciate that!  Just adding to the discussion myself.  :)

Comment: I'd think that having separate tags for various types of _flight_ training is too noisy at this stage, though if a clear group of questions emerge I'm more than happy to allow for a new tag.